# jQuery changing the size of Video players

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, width

James here. I'm working on a project (actually two projects that both require the same code) that deals with posts, except the content is always 100% of the users screen, and uses jquery to divide the width to make the same amount of columns no matter what screen resolution. I'm having a trouble with video posts however. If anyone could help me write (or write, that'd be way more helpful) a script that forces a default 500px video to the width of the posts? The script that I'm using to divide posts is as follows. Any answers at ALL would be helpful. Oh and I'm bumping this because it's almost a week old, and I have still not received a working script.

```
    var container = function(){
    var posts = $(document).width() - 40;
    var entry = (posts - 200) / 5;
    $("#posts").css("width", posts);
    $(".entry").css("width", entry);
    $("img.photo").css("width", entry - 22);
}

container();
```

The site I'm doing this on is http://jamestestblog5.tumblr.com
Thank you to anyone who can help with this, it's REALLY bothering me!

Comment: Which video player do you use?

Comment: I don't control that, tumblr does. This is all on a Tumblr theme. D: It can be YouTube, Vimeo, or Tumblr's player... I would prefer a script that works no matter what (not depending on the company player if you know what I mean). That's why I have the code for iframes, embeds, and objects.

Comment: Hiya James Can I flick you a jsfiddle instead of you using the cod eyou mentioned above? its a working example with tumblr else you can provide the jsfiddle I can see what I can do, cheers bruv!

Answer (score 1):

Hiya please see **demo here** : http://jsfiddle.net/ytcAk/

you can read the logic when you click grow button.

fork from old solution. :) (please let me know if this is what you are looking for if not I will remove this post)

**Jquery code**

```
function increaseVideoSize() {
    var columnWidth = 450; // width of your content column - any
    var defaultVideoWidth = 400; // theme tag width - 400,500
    var increaseRatio = columnWidth/defaultVideoWidth;
    $(".video-post").each(function() {
        var iframe = $("iframe", this);
        if(iframe.length>0) {
            var currHeight = iframe.height();
            var newHeight = currHeight * increaseRatio;
            iframe.height(newHeight).width(columnWidth);
        } else {
            var object = $("object", this);
            var embed = $("embed", object);
            var currHeight = object.attr('height');
            var newHeight = currHeight * increaseRatio;
            object.width(columnWidth).attr('height', newHeight);
            embed.width(columnWidth).attr('height', newHeight);
        };
    });
};​
```

Comment: I'm new to this... Would you mind embedding that same code into the one I used before? Obviously replacing my (stupid attempt) to resize the videos. And yes that does seem to be what I'm looking for... I just need help putting it all into one code.

Comment: Hiya @JamesCharless you can replace your resize function with the one mention above `increaseVideoSize` and make sure your class is set collect i.e. `".video-post"` it will all work fine ; **Jsfiddle** will help you to see how it fits together and slice the code from jsfiddle to your code and try it out, hope this helps! cheers bruv!

Comment: Could you provide one big code? (My original one + Your new one)? It'd make it a lot easier for me, and I don't know how I'd combine the two.

Comment: Hiya @JamesCharless try some attempts bruv; I can give you tips it will be hard for me to merge your code **Don't worry** about it because you simply need to place the jsfiddle code inside your code and remove or comment out the old resizing code d'uh obviously since you are new it will take few attempts but think like you think about objects in any language let me know how it goes

Comment: http://jamestestblog5.tumblr.com/ It's not working and it breaks when infinite scroll is activated. :c

Comment: @JamesCharless that was a very fast attempt lol :) any who when I checked view source of your page i cannot see this code i.e. this function ? `increaseVideoSize` and from where you are calling it?

Comment: @JamesCharless lets chat man invite me for chat, where have you set your tags `<p><input type="button" onclick="increaseVideoSize(); $(this).hide()" value="Grow" /></p>​` something like this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10337/discussion-between-jamescharless-and-tats-innit)